# How can I tell if one TClass is derived from another?

Tags: delphi, class, delphi-7

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
function CreateIfForm ( const nClass : TClass ) : TForm;
begin
  if not ( nClass is TFormClass ) then
    raise Exception.Create( 'Not a form class' );
  Result := ( nClass as TFormClass ).Create( Application );
end;
```

This produces error "Operator not applicable to this operand type".
I'm using Delphi 7.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First you should check if you can change the function to accept only a form class:

```
function CreateIfForm(const nClass: TFormClass): TForm;
```

and bypass the need for type checking and casting.

If this isn't posssible, you can use [`InheritsFrom`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.TObject.InheritsFrom):

```
function CreateIfForm(const nClass: TClass): TForm;
begin
  if not nClass.InheritsFrom(TForm) then
    raise Exception.Create('Not a form class');
  Result := TFormClass(nClass).Create(Application);
end;
```

Comment: InheritsFrom!   Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for.  Thanks

Comment: @Ulrich -- Your second answer is really the correct one:  The function should never even accept a class that isn't a form.

Comment: @Nick, your right of course. I rephrased my answer to better reflect this.